# Is it possible to get PDB symbol files from .appxbundle?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working with UPW and just built a package (`.appxbundle`) for testing purposes... I've installed it on a remote computer and would like to attach my debugger to the process. But it seems my break points won't hit unless I have the `PDB` symbol files. Is there anyway to extract the `PDB` symbol files from the `.appxbundle`. I've got the setting to make them toggled.

Any other ideas would be a great help.

Thanks

EDIT: I've found the `PDB` symbol files inside the `bin` folder... I'll try them out.

EDIT: Those symbol files didn't appear to work...

EDIT: Scratch that it worked! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look in your `bin` folder...

e.g. `C:\Users\visc\Documents\git\WindowsProject\MyProject\bin\x64\Release`